# Regex conversion from Java to mysql for '?:'

Tags: mysql, regex

I have this Expression

```
(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

that is working fine in java but when i am trying to use the same in mySql it is giving me 
Error Code: 1139
Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

So when i replace above Expression with this

```
(((^25[0-5])|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}((^25[0-5])|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

This is giving me some additional Results?
Plz let me know what i am Doing Wrong , Thanks For your time

Comment: Fetch only correct results? Can we choose ourselves the data set and the definition of correct? ;-P

Comment: i have two result sets..one from java and other pne from mySql, and as mysql resultset have all the values from java result plus additional info, i concluded additional info (Redundant ) is added courtesy my query in sql!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct `?:` is a non-capturing group.
When refering to the current [documentation of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) one can see that it

> is aimed at conformance with POSIX 1003.2

and that

> MySQL uses the extended version

In other words, it uses `POSIX ERE` and this flavor *simply doesn't support non-capturing groups*.
For a detailed listing on what constructs are available in Java and in POSIX ERE you can use [regular-expressions.info as a reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), specifically [this site for capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) (just be sure to choose `Java` and `POSIX ERE` in the two dropdowns).

As to why you get additional results:
Did you notice that your regexes aren't equal?
In the first and second half of your first regex you write `(?:25[0-5]|`, while in the second regex this becomes `((^25[0-5])|`.
A `^` matches the beginning of a string ([here's the documentation again](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)), so at least the second occurence can never match if anything was matched before.

Perhaps you want to use this regex in MySQL, but i can only take a guess here as i don't know your data and what exactly you want to match.

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

I just took your first regex and removed all `?:`.

Comment: This regex will include all the strings where any numeric value with more than 6 digits are present.

Comment: `any numeric value with more than 6 digits` - are you sure your regex is correct? A numeric value with more than 6 digits would be, for example `1234567` and your regex won't match this. For your original question concerning the conversion of `?:` my answer is above. If you have a problem with the regex itself (if it doesn't match your input or what ever) I suggest opening a new question with example input and desired output.